# Program stops responding after clicking on information in Data Grid View

Tags: c#, winforms

everytime I click on any user in my Data Grid View program stops responding and gives me an error that tells me "System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Arg_ParamName_Name'" The part that shows me this error is

```
VartotojoID.Text = VartotojuDGV.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
```

Comment: well if your datagrid does not have any row selected....

Comment: looks like `SelectedRows[0]` is empty or the subsequent `.Cells[0]` call is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
VartotojoID.Text = VartotojuDGV.SelectedRows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().FirstOrDefault()?.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
```

**Updated**
Old Collection you'll need to cast first sorry

Comment: It doesn't crash anymore, that's good, however, the selected things don't appear in my textBoxes that I have despite setting them to be that

Comment: configure `VartotojuDGV.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;`

Comment: that way you always select a whole row

Comment: either in the designer or in code (right after databind or so)